# SQL Creating a cumulative sum column in a table by a specific order

Tags: sql, grouping, sql-server-2016

I apologize for the confusing title. I am dealing with an issue this morning that I thought I solved with everyone's help here but I can't do what I originally had hoped with just the master_line_num. Once again, below is a small subset of the data I am working with:

```
ID  Proj_Id    Year   Quarter  Value  **Cumu_Value**      Master_Line_Num
1   "C102"     2017      1    200.00    **200.00**           1
2   "C102"     2017      2    200.00    **400.00**           2
3   "C102"     2017      3    200.00    **600.00**           3
4   "C102"     2017      4    200.00    **800.00**           4
5   "C102"     2018      1    400.00    **1200.00**          5 
6   "C102"     2018      2    400.00    **1600.00**          6
7   "C102"     2018      3    400.00    **2000.00**          7
8   "C102"     2018      4    400.00    **2400.00**          8  
9   "B123"     2017      1    100.00    **100.00**           1
10  "B123"     2017      2    100.00    **200.00**           2
11  "B123"     2017      3    100.00    **300.00**           3
12  "B123"     2017      4    100.00    **400.00**           4            
13  "B123"     2018      1    200.00    **600.00**           5
14  "B123"     2018      2    200.00    **800.00**           6
15  "B123"     2018      3    200.00    **1000.00**          7
16  "B123"     2018      4    200.00    **1200.00**          8
```

The desired values I am trying to get is the "Cumu_Value" column. I am trying to get those values by adding up the "value" column by year, by quarter for a specific "Proj_Id". I originally just tried to multiply the "value" column by the master_line_num column after getting that but then realized that it doesn't work due to the "value" column changing between years.

Is it possible to calculate this with T-SQL or do I need to do something more extravagant?

Comment: Try analytic functions.

Answer (score 2):

SQL supports the cumulative sum as a window function, so this is easy to express:

```
select . . . ,
      sum(value) over (partition by proj_id order by year, quarter) as cumulative_sum
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a Windowed Aggregate, this will return a Cumulative Sum:

```
sum(value) 
over (partition by proj_id 
      order by Year, Quarter
      rows unbounded preceding)
```

Caution, don't use `(partition by proj_id order by Year, Quarter)` without the `ROWS` as it defaults to `RANGE` which might return a different result and has much more overhead. `RANGE` includes all rows with the same value as the current. In your case it would return:

```
 800
 800
 800
 800
2400
2400
2400
2400
```

Edit:

After checking your other question I noticed that you don't have a `Master_Line_Num` in your data, so you better use `ORDER BY Year, Quarter` instead.

Comment: @user3494110: When it works, you should *accept* this answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
 select t1.id, t1.proj_ID, t1.Year, t1.Value, SUM(t2.Value) as Cumu_sum, Master_Line_Num
    from @tablename t1
    inner join @tablename t2 on t1.id >= t2.id
    group by t1.id, t1.Value
    order by t1.id
```